# Extend filelock even the program is not running

Tags: java, filelock, java.nio.file

Im having trouble with the files that I want to lock permanently. My program can lock the files but when I exit the program (the program is not running) the lock will be release. I want to lock files even the program is not running, is it possible? here's my code. Please help me

```
        import java.io.*;
        import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
        import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
        import java.nio.file.Path;
        import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
        import static com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedOpenOption.NOSHARE_DELETE;
        import static com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedOpenOption.NOSHARE_READ;
        import static com.sun.nio.file.ExtendedOpenOption.NOSHARE_WRITE;
        import java.nio.channels.FileLock;

        public class LockFile {

            public static void ProcessPackageFiles2(File Path) {
                try {
                    File[] files = Path.listFiles();
                    for (File file : files) {
                        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                            LockDown(file.getCanonicalPath());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public static void LockDown(String FilePath) {

                try {

                    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(FilePath);
                    FileChannel locks = FileChannel.open(path, NOSHARE_WRITE, NOSHARE_DELETE, NOSHARE_READ);
                    FileLock fileLock = locks.tryLock();

                    if (fileLock != null) {
                        System.out.println("Locked");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FAILED");
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }

            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                ProcessPackageFiles2(new File(path);
            }
```

[this is the result when I run the program. The file will be unreadable and 
  cannot be shared and deleted. But I want to extend it even the program is not 
  running. But the question is HOW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvTvF.png)

Comment: Your code lacks indentation and is unreadable because of that. Please, edit your code formatting.

Comment: Locks are used to prevent access to the file while your process is working with it. No process - no need to keep the lock on file. Unless you could run a background bash script to do that this is not possible.

Comment: you can only revoke access for all users, but the owner can still access the file

Comment: Yes sir. Thats what I mean. The owner can access it if he/she use the program